# How to navigate from component in react bottom tab navigator to screen navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, asyncstorage, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Before I explain my problem, let me show the file structure of my react native project:

```
--- App.js (main file where most the project routing is stored. Main, login and signup stack.screen )
------|
      |-- <Stack.Screen> Main component (main component stores the bottom navigation tabs)
      |         |
      |         |-- <Tab.Screen> Home bottom tab
      |         |-- <Tab.Screen> Activity bottom tab
      |         |-- <Tab.Screen> Settings bottom tab ( this is where the problem arises )
      |
      |
      |-- <Stack.Screen> Login component
      |-- <Stack.Screen> Signup component
```

The settings bottom tab displays the setting component. The settings component has the logout function. The logout function clears the asyncstorage and once the asyncstorage is cleared I want the component to redirect to the login component from the `Apps.js` file.

Below is the code from my Settings component

PS. this is a class component

```
logOutPress = async() =>
{
     try {
          await AsyncStorage.clear();
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
     } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error clearing AsyncStorage:', error);
     }
}

render ()
{
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Sign out" onPress={() => {this.logOutPress()}} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

However, after the the button press and asyncstorage is cleared, when the project has to redirect, the error below appears:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.

Followed by:

> Do you have a screen named 'Login'?

Than this suggestion:

```
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stack is not properly organized

Think Whick Screen you want to render first when opening app,
That you have to load first on Bottom Tab

And sayway you need to render BottomTab Component first

```
const Route = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const BottomTab = () => {
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="ActivityScreen" component={ActivityScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>;
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="BottomTab"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SettingScreen" component={SettingScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ActivityScreen" component={ActivityScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="PracticeScreen" component={PracticeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="BottomTab" component={BottomTab} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Try Implementing this!
It works